# Rails auto_html gem help - Not saving as html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to create form that uses the auto_html gem on the text_area body_html. I have follow this guide [how to create the auto_html on a text_area.](https://github.com/dejan/auto_html)

I have that problem that the preview dont gets rendered without a browser refresh and the text_area body_html gets not saved as html code just as plain text.

My model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  auto_html_for :body_html do
    html_escape
    image
    youtube(:width => 400, :height => 250)
    link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
    simple_format
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
include AutoHtml


  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.xml
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end


  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.xml
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My new form:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function load(request) {
  $('#code').text(request);
  $('#preview').html(request);
}

function preview(value) {
  $.getJSON("http://auto_html.rors.org/comments/preview?callback=?", value, function(data){
    load(data);
  });
}

function previewComment() {
  preview({'t':$('#comment_body').val()});
}

$('#examples a').click(function() {
  $('#comment_body').focus(); 
  $('#comment_body').val( $(this).attr('href'));
  previewComment();
});

$(function () { 
  $("#comment_body").focus();
  previewComment();
});

$('#comment_form').delayedObserver(1, function(element, value) { previewComment() })
</script>

<h1>New post</h1>

<form id="comment_form" action="/posts" method="post">
<h3>Type or paste URLs</h3>

<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :titel, :label => 'Titel', :style => 'width:500;' %>
    <%= f.text_area :body_html, :id => 'comment_body', :label => '125x125', :style => 'width:500;' %>
    <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Create post' %>
<% end %>
<h3>Code</h3>
<div id="code"></div>
<h3>Preview</h3>
<div id="preview"></div>
</form>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using extra sufix _*html*

Use *body* on inputs (and declaring auto_html_for in model) and *body_html* on outputs

You basically need to change to this:

```
auto_html_for :body
```

And in form:

```
...
<%= f.text_area :body, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For your problem saved it as html.
You can try this:

```
def body_html
auto_html(self[:body_html]) { simple_format; link(:target => 'blank') }
end
```

or

```
 auto_html self[:body_html] do
    html_escape
    image
    youtube(:width => 400, :height => 250)
    link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
    simple_format
  end
  end
```